# Disable delete when you got only one 1 existing file with specific name

Tags: vb.net

How i can hide delete.button and change it with another button with warning that you only have 1 operation manager you cannot delete again. when i have only one (Position= Operation manager) in my datagridview

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form5

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim comm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim query As String

    Private Sub Form5_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.LogInTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LogInDataSet.LogIn)

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
        "Data Source = C:\Users\69neers\Desktop\Database\Program\Program\bin\Debug\LogIn.accdb; " & _
        "Persist Security Info=false"
        conn.Open()


        query = "SELECT * FROM LogIn WHERE Uname = '" & UnameTextBox.Text & "'"
        comm.CommandText = query
        comm.Connection = conn
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader

        dr.Read()


        If LogInBindingSource.Count = 1 And dr("Pos") = PosComboBox.Text Then
            btndelete.Enabled = False
            btndelete.Hide()
            btndelalter.Show()
            btndelete.Enabled = False
        Else
            btndelete.Enabled = True
            btndelalter.Hide()
            btndelete.Show()
        End If



        dr.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: This is too vague. Could you please elaborate more? Where do you call this code and what is `LogInBindingSource`?

Comment: can you help me with that T_T

Comment: I think I understand _what_ you want to do, however I don't understand _when_ you want to do it. You check `LogInBindingSource` (which I still don't know what it is) in `Form_Load`... Does the code work so far, that is, does it do what you want if you open the form and `.Count = 1`?

Comment: Per my understanding you want this to be checked frequently rather than the first time the form is opened, correct? If so, then you need to run that code snippet every time your data is updated (edited, removed, added, etc.). I don't know much about databases, but if your binding source implements some kind of notification system you can utilize that.

Comment: You should look into parameterized queries. The way you're currently putting data into your sql commands is scary.

Comment: The `BindingSource` class (if that's what you're using) has got some events that can be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource_events(v=vs.110).aspx